# Python - User input for specific folder in directory, then print all contents of directory

Tags: python, directory

Scripts is supposed to accept user input and print out all contents of a folder in a specific format. Example: Folder1(main folder)-->Folder2-->Folder3-->Folder4.

Directory contains mnemonics(Folder1) with format **mnemonic:contents**

Contents may contain subfolders.

What I have here is throwing this error: *Valueerror too many values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)*

in this line: "**for single_mnemonic, contents in os.listdir(startpath):**"

```
def search_specific_mnemonic(startpath):
user_entered_mnemonic = input("Enter Client Mnemonic: ")
facility_types = ["clinic", "hospital", "lab", "hub_millennium", "client_millennium"]

for single_mnemonic, contents in os.listdir(startpath):

    CRED = "\033[91m"
    CEND = "\033[0m"
    print(CRED + "\n",user_entered_mnemonic + CEND)

    for facility_type in facility_types:
        if contents[facility_type]:
            box_display_char = "X"
        else:
            box_display_char = "_"

        print("  [{0}] - {1}".format(box_display_char, facility_type.replace("_", " ").title()))
        if contents[facility_type]:
            for practice_name in sorted(contents[facility_type]):
                print("     {}".format(practice_name))
                for practice_scripts in sorted(contents[facility_type]):
                    print("         {}".format(contents[facility_type][practice_name]))
                    break
```

Comment: @PM2Ring I updated the script and took out parse_directory as it wasnt needed for this purpose. Here is the error: Valueerror too many values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) in this line "for single_mnemonic, contents in os.listdir(startpath):"

Comment: Ah, ok I didn't notice that earlier. :oops: On closer inspection, I don't understand several elements of your code. `os.listdir(startpath)` returns a list of file / folder names  in `startpath`. You'd normally loop over those strings with something like `for fname in os.listdir(startpath):`. So why do you have `single_mnemonic, contents`? Later in your code you appear to be treating `contents` as if it were a dictionary.

Comment: @PM2Ring I honestly don't know, fairly new to python. Im wondering if i need to start all over on this..

Comment: It would help us to understand what you're trying to do if you could gave us a small sample of what the `startpath` folder contains, typical user input that would be typed in response to `input("Enter Client Mnemonic: ")`, and the expected output for that folder contents & user input.

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain all file names in your folder are of the same format
(i.e mnemonic:content)
You could try:
`for single_mnemonic, contents in [format_name.split(':') for format_name in os.listdir(startpath):`

This will return an array, where's every item is a an array of the two sides of the formatted name: [[mnemonic, content], [mnemonic, content]]